# Interpolation prevented by ngClass function in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-class

I encounter an odd issue using a responsive sidebar in Angular 6 (https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) and I'm completely unable to interpolate into the sidebar. I love this sidebar, and its strange router animation powers, and I have got to figure out how to work around this...

```
sidebar.component.ts (the title property) 

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
selector: 'app-sidebar',
templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
hide = '';
isActive = false;
showMenu = '';
pushRightClass = 'push-right';
title = 'title';
constructor(public router: Router) {
  this.title = 'title';
this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
  if (
      val instanceof NavigationEnd &&
      window.innerWidth <= 992 &&
      this.isToggled()
  ) {
      console.log('S1');
      this.toggleSidebar();
  }
  });
```

}

And then in sidebar.component.html:

```
<nav class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{sidebarPushRight: isActive}">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a routerLink="/" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" 
class="list-group-item">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>{{title}}
    </a>
   </div> 
</nav>
```

It must have something to do with the css, or the functions, but I can't find it:

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try add ' ' around the class name:
[ngClass]="{'sidebarPushRight': isActive}"

Comment: I don’t think I explained this well: {{title}} isn’t showing up, sidebarPushRight works just fine. You right ‘title’ in the html document - perfect, you change it to an interpolation from a property in the .ts file and it’s gone.

Comment: of course, like you wrote the value inside the interpolation directive ( the {{}} brackets ) should not be with ' '.
Just to make the case more easier to solve - can you change the value of the title field to 'some title'. lets continue from there - what do you see now?